# How to integrate Magento Store and display products into wordpress theme/ website?

Tags: wordpress, magento

I am a newbie to eCommerce, and in process of developing a website for my upcoming eCommerce store from scratch.

I have been working with WordPress "Albar " theme. After researching I found Magento to go ahead with my store.

I have installed Magento through Hostgator ( Hosting service), I am somewhat familiar with adding products , but not able to get a solution to display the products to my website , ie; on WordPress theme.

How to link the store to website ? I have come across WordPress Integration plugins , but still couldn't find a solution.

By default there are some pages appearing in the Magento > CMS > Pages and in preview it opens with the link after my domain name.

Kindly help me out with this problem.

Regards ,

JD

Answer (score 0):

You have to write extension for Magento that adds new controller which return json with products. In Wordpress create ajax request that reads this json and displays products.

Comment: Well i could find a plugin from jckemp Magento WordPress Integration. The tool has worked fine with the procedures given on jckemp.com . I just want to know the next step after the plugin integration.

Comment: Thanks , I got a tool from FISHpig , Magento intergration .